# How do I change the size of a liquid simulation?

Tags: mesh

I want to add some delicious honey to my waffle but since my waffle is only like 10cm big the liquid simulation comes out way too big. How can I change the size of these 'balls' and thus change the liquid size. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe first try to increase the *Resolution* of the *Domain* (it will decrease the size of the mesh faces), also under *Liquid*, decrease *Particle Radius* (it will decrease the thickness of the mesh around the particles), and increase the *Sampling* a bit (it will increase the amount of particles):

[image]